# how to remove rdp force mstsc /admin

Tags: remote-desktop, session-manager

I'm at work and here I have got 5 server running windows server 2008 r2.
One of this 5, force me to use mstsc /admin to remote access.
hint: remote desktop session host is active in this one and I think License Evaluation has expired.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the renewed RDP client. It can be downloaded from MS. Version 8 is the updated one.

Comment: I found this on Microsoft web page : Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2592687). after download installer pop message "this update already installed on this computer"

Comment: It needs to be updated. It is not necessary to remove it before, unless other errors occur.